# Wordpress - Get All Rows In HTML Table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, foreach

I have a custom wordpress table and am trying to get all rows in the db separated by year. My code now:

```
echo "<table width='100%'>";
for ($year = date("Y"); $year >= 2017; --$year) {         
    echo ("<tr><th>$year</th></tr>");       
    echo ("<tr><th>Champions</th>");

    echo ("<th>Score</th>");

    echo ("<th>Date</th></tr>");

  global $wpdb;
        $clubmatch = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_club ORDER BY gamedate DESC");

    foreach($clubmatch as $row){

      echo "<tr><td>" . $row->names . "</td>";   
        echo "<td>" . $row->score . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row->gamedate . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo ("<tr><td style='padding: 20px;'></td></tr>");   


} 
echo '</table>';
```

This gives me the following on screen:

```
2018
Champions   Score   Date
Sam Jones - Peggy Jones    81.43    2018-03-01
Joseph Parks - Carmen Parks    70.85    2017-12-17

2017
Champions   Score   Date
Sam Jones - Peggy Jones    81.43    2018-03-01
Joseph Parks - Carmen Parks    70.85    2017-12-17
```

How do I get it to show like this?  Each row under the proper year?

```
2018
Champions   Score   Date
Sam Jones - Peggy Jones    81.43    2018-03-01

2017
Champions   Score   Date
Joseph Parks - Carmen Parks    70.85    2017-12-17
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the SQL query, so that it filters the result by the year of the field `gamedate`. So use this: (the code is indented for clarity)

```
$clubmatch = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT * FROM wp_club " .
    "WHERE YEAR(gamedate) = '$year' " .
    "ORDER BY gamedate DESC"
);
```

..instead of:

```
$clubmatch = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_club ORDER BY gamedate DESC");
```

Comment: Thank you Sally!  Works as expected now!